# Activity is starting slowly

Tags: android, android-activity, lag, layout-inflater, android-inflate

There are several buttons in my app. New activity starts quickly whenever i press any button except for one. It lags to open a new activity.Why it is lagging ?
 Here is the code snipet :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChooseActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constant.MP_REQUEST);
```

ChooseActivity.class:

```
    ChooseActivityHelper mActivityHelper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    mActivityHelper = new ChooseActivityHelper(this);

    mActivityHelper.inflateView();
}
```

ChooseActivityHelper:

```
public ChooseActivityHelper(Context ctx) {
    mCurrentTabIndex = 1;
    mContext = ctx;
}

// inflate data to view
    @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
    public void inflateView() {
        ChooseActivity act = (ChooseActivity) mContext;
        try {
            assMngr = act.getAssets();
            String[] folders = assMngr.list(Constant._FOLDER);
            for (String f : folders) {
                inflateTabView(f);
                stampFolderList.add(f);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it is lagging when i hit that particular button. all the related codes are given. If you need any other code snippet please tell me.